# Probability of 3 confidence intervals failing to capture the true parameter

Tags: probability, confidence-interval

Suppose I collected 3 random samples (each of size n) from the same population. I calculated three estimates (of the same parameter) and three 95% confidence intervals (for the same parameter).

What is the probability that **all** 3 intervals **failed** to capture the true parameter value? If I assume the confidence intervals are independent and all the statistical model assumptions are met:

$$F = (1-0.95)^3$$
$$F = 0.000125$$

There is a 0.0125% probability that all 3 intervals failed to capture the true parameter.

I have several questions:

1. What is the harm of interpreting a 95% confidence interval as there is a 95% probability that a random interval contains a fixed parameter value? A single confidence interval may or may not contain the true parameter. Why can't I quantify the "not knowing" with probability?
2. Why do frequentists have to come up with round-about statements like, "There's a 95% chance that the next sample would generate a 95% confidence interval that contains the true value." If the probabilities are independent, isn't the 95% probability applicable to both the current and next sample?
3. How could you answer the "all 3 intervals fail to capture the parameter" question without assuming that the "95%" is a probability?
4. Does the answer of 1.25% depend on whether the 3 confidence intervals are realized (calculated) or yet to be realized (yet to be calculated)? Does it matter whether the first 2 sentences are in past tense?

The question is heavily related to [Why aren't these sentences about confidence intervals equivalent?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/564153/why-arent-these-sentences-about-confidence-intervals-equivalent).

Update: 08/17/2022: Henry found a math mistake.

Comment: $(1-0.95)^3 = 0.000125$ which is $0.0125\%$ not $1.25\%$

Comment: Your questions 1 and 2 have been asked many times before, such as at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26450 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6652 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11609 while your question 4 (from a frequentist perspective) has the answer "yes" and that affects the answer to question 3

Comment: (1) is the standard interpretation of a confidence interval.  The alleged frequentist interpretation in (2) is incorrect.  (3) is baflling--what would the 95% mean otherwise? (4) also is strange due to an unconventional interpretation of both confidence and probability.

Comment: Thank you, Henry. I fixed the math mistake.

Comment: @whuber - I got #2 from Wiki (which cites Neyman 1937). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Interpretation

Comment: Thank you.  What bothers me about that phrasing is the reference to the *next* sample.  That's irrelevant to discussing *this* sample.  So, although technically the description is correct, it's misleading.